# Tensorflow - Qual melhor modelo para realizar o treinamento de notas do real?

Tags: processamento-de-imagens, redes-neurais, tensorflow

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de faculdade para realizar o reconhecimento das notas do real por meio do TensorFlow, mas o grande problema é que as cédulas do real possuem muita semelhança entre elas, principalmente na parte de trás da cédula, outro problema é a falta de um dataset com boa qualidade das cédulas novas do real, sendo assim é necessário a criação de um dataset com imagens de boa qualidade e pode ser que neste ponto estou sendo falho.

Realizei a configuração de todo o TensorFlow no windows e segui o tutorial (https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) e lá ele usa o modelo Faster-RCNN-Inception-V2-COCO e com as imagens que tenho usando esse modelo os valores do loss está muito alto (Muito Alto Mesmo) gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem algum outro modelo que seria muito bom para o meu cenário e se teriam algumas dicas contornar esses problemas de similaridade.

[image: Valor de Loss Extremamente Alto]
[image: Parte de trás da nota de 2 reais]
[image: Parte de trás da nota de 50 reais]

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você seguiu o tutorial corretamente, o problema pode vir de dois lugares:

1. Dados: poucos dados, dados incompletos, dataset desbalanceado
2. Hiperparametros

Vamos começar com dados: redes *deep learning* precisam de muitos dados, mas são muitos mesmo, e é por isso que elas estão na moda, finalmente temos o que fazer com todos os nossos dados, você disse que não existem bons datasets de nota de real, então vá a uma caixa eletrônico, saca umas notas, troca no posto pelas de 2 e 5, pega o seu celular e começa a fotografar, lembre-se de usar a mesma iluminação e background para os diferentes tipos de nota, assim a rede aprende a ignorar essas informações. Ou, se vc precisar de uma solução mais fácil: *data augmentation*, consiste em técnicas para gerar novos dados a partir dos dados que você já tem: inverter a imagem, deslocar ela alguns pixels pra esquerda ou direita, fazer cropping etc...

Hiperparametros: são os ajustes finos do seu modelo, *learning rate*, e outros parametros do seu otimizador, as vezes mexer um pouquinho neles pode ajudar o modelo a convergir mais rápido

Eu trabalhei um pouco com a FasteR-CNN e posso dizer que é mto boa, parece que o tutorial tá fazendo *transfer learning*, retreinando só as ultimas camadas da rede, mas se você não for fazer isso em tempo real (procesando um video por exemplo) da pra usar uma rede um pouco menos potente

Answer (score 0):

Para reconhecimento de padrões poderia utilizar rede Neural convolucional (CNN) - arquitetura VGGNet base de algum bons modelos de redes neurais, como o  modelo CAFFE reconhece o padrão : https://cocodataset.org/#home abstraindo cores e objetos como a marca d'agua nas cedulas.